# Срезы в фильтрах django

Tags: python, django, запрос

Пытаюсь применить срезы к выборке, чтобы ограничить ее. Насколько я понял [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets), то это должно ограничить выборку 10-ю записями:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    qs = Message.objects.all()  
    qs = qs.filter(Target_id=self.dialog)[0:10] 
    qs = qs.annotate(sender_id=Max('Sender__id')) 
    return qs
```

Но по факту запрос возвращает мне все записи, но применяет аннотацию лишь к 10-ти первым.

Генерируемый запрос - через Django DebugToolbar - выглядит так:

> SELECT "main_message"."id", "main_message"."Sender_id",
>   "main_message"."Time", "main_message"."Content",
>   "main_message"."Target_id", MAX("main_message"."Sender_id") AS
>   "sender_id" FROM "main_message" WHERE "main_message"."Target_id" =
>   '22' GROUP BY "main_message"."id", "main_message"."Sender_id",
>   "main_message"."Time", "main_message"."Content",
>   "main_message"."Target_id" LIMIT 10

Пробовал так же ограничивать через slice в шаблоне:

```
{% for message in messages|slice:":10" %}
```

Но результат тот же. **Как сделать,чтобы срез применялся не к аннотации записей, а к количеству выбранных записей?**

Comment: Забавно, что если я выполню этот запрос в самой БД, то получу только 10 записей. И в `len(qs)` получаю 10. Но при итерации в шаблоне получаю все 300 сообщений - все, что есть в бд. Как отловить, откуда получаются все эти сообщения?

Comment: Может, это какой-то джанговский кэш?

Comment: Если убрать аннотацию, то же самое - при срезе в шаблоне получаю все сообщения! Единственная разница, что со срезом страница генерируется в три раза быстрее, а без него - 400мс

Comment: Пытался так же сделать list(qs), но получаю ошибку `TemplateDoesNotExist`. Связи не вижу, но факт

Comment: хм, к последней ошибке приводит любая попытка во view калькулировать queryset. Например, `qs[::0]` приводит к той же ошибке

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю след вариант.

Вы сначала выбираете ID записей, для которых будет аннтотация, а потом применяете аннотацию

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    qs = Message.objects.all()  

    ids_for_annotate = qs.filter(Target_id=self.dialog).values_list('id', flat=True)[0:10] 

    qs = qs.filter(id__in=ids_for_annotate).annotate(sender_id=Max('Sender__id')) 
    return qs
```

---

Если же вам нужно выбрать часть из всех аннотаций сообщений, то тогда поменяйте строчки аннтотации и ограничения выборки местами

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    qs = Message.objects.all()  
    qs = qs.annotate(sender_id=Max('Sender__id'))
    qs = qs.filter(Target_id=self.dialog)[0:10]  
    return qs
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. К сожалению (или к счастью), проблема крылась совсем не в этом: у меня сразу после загрузки get отправлялся post-запрос  с лонгпул ajax-ом. который подбирал все остальные сообщения. А тк этот ajax выполнялся мгновенно при загрузке страницы, я по ошибке считал, что все эти данные приходили с get и за целый день чуть голову не сломал над этой проблемой))